# OS X 10.9 - Home Directory for Share Only Account?

Tags: macos, user-account, accounts

I created a new Share Only user account but I am not able to find the home directory for this account in Finder, or under /Users.

I know for sure that the account was created correctly, because when I try to recreate the same Share Only Account, the system tells me that an account of this type already exists.

Where can I find the home directory for this specific account?

My other accounts (Standard User Account, Administrative User Account and Parental Control User Account) appear in the /Users directory.

Answer (score 1):

Sharing Only accounts do not have home folders. Home folders are really only used during a local login session, and Sharing Only users cannot log in locally, there's no real point to having one.

If you want a Sharing Only account to have a their own private file storage location, create a folder (where doesn't really matter), use System Preferences -> Sharing pane -> File Sharing service to add it to the shared folder list, then set the owner to the Sharing account (and optionally limit access for other users).